# Wait until class is removed from a div

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium with C# to test a Web App. We have an implementation that when a section of a page is loading, we add a class to the div of the section and once the section has been loaded, the div class is removed from the div. For example:

Before

```
<div class="tabs-container spinner">
```

After:

```
<div class="tabs-container">
```

I am trying to add a Wait until the spinner is removed from the div class. I tried using

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("spinner")));
```

', however, this doesn't work.

Any idea how to handle this case?

Comment: Did you correctly uploaded Before/After parts?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using css selector.Try with `.classname`

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector(".spinner")));
```

---

Or You can check `.spinner` class is not present using `ElementIsVisible`

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div.tabs-container:not(.spinner)")));
```

Comment: You're looking for an invisible .spinner instead of the particular element to not be .spinner. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @pguardiario : Updated the answer with `ElementIsVisible` with .spinner class not present.However 1st option should work as per OP looking after.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the removal of the **loader** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `InvisibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("div.tabs-container.spinner")));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//div[@class='tabs-container spinner']")));
  ```

Comment: This is not even close.

Comment: @pguardiario Close to what?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function to wait for change in `class` attribute  like

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, string> waitForChangeInAttribute(By locator, string attribute, string notValue) {
    return (driver) => {
      try {
          var value = driver.FindElement(locator).GetAttribute(attribute);
          return value == notValue ? null : value;
      }
      catch (NoSuchElementException) {
          return null;
      }
      catch (StaleElementReferenceException) {
          return null;
      }
    };
}
```

And you use/call like

```
string valueBefore = driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'tabs-')]")).GetAttribute(attribute);

wait.Until(waitForChangeInAttribute(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'tabs-')]"), "class", valueBefore));
```

**Note: Please take care of single and double quote as I am typing from Mobile keypad**

Answer (score 0):

You could create a quick hacky method with a while loop.

```
    ...
    CheckLoaded("div[class*='spinner']", 5);

    public void CheckLoaded(string css, int timeout)
    {
        timeout = timeout * 1000;
        int count=0;
        while(driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(css) > 0 || count < timeout))
        {
             Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know Thread.Sleep is bad - but just a quick way to get round his problem.